# Time complexity of a sliding window question

Tags: python, substring, time-complexity, sliding-window

I'm working on the following problem:

*Given a string and a list of words, find all the starting indices of substrings in the given string that are a concatenation of all the given words exactly once without any overlapping of words. It is given that all words are of the same length. For example:*

**Input: String = "catfoxcat", Words = ["cat", "fox"]

Output: [0, 3]

Explanation: The two substring containing both the words are "catfox" & "foxcat".**

My solution is:

```
def find_word_concatenation(str, words):
  result_indices = []
  period = len(words[0])
  startIndex = 0
  wordCount = {}
  matched = 0
  for w in words:
    if w not in wordCount:
      wordCount[w] = 1
    else:
      wordCount[w] += 1

  for endIndex in range(0, len(str) - period + 1, period):
    rightWord = str[endIndex: endIndex + period]
    if rightWord in wordCount:
      wordCount[rightWord] -= 1
      if wordCount[rightWord] == 0:
        matched += 1
    while matched == len(wordCount):
      if endIndex + period - startIndex  == len(words)*period:
        result_indices.append(startIndex)
      leftWord = str[startIndex: startIndex + period]
      if leftWord in wordCount:
        wordCount[leftWord] += 1
        if wordCount[leftWord] > 0:
          matched -= 1
      startIndex += period
      
  return result_indices
```

Can anyone help me figure out its time complexity please?

Comment: Do you know if there will always be just two words?

Comment: No, there can be any number of words, but all the words will be the same length.

Comment: The length of the words really isn't a big deal. But here's another question to get clear on what exactly you need for an answer: Say you have three words in your wordlist. Would you be expecting (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1), (2,3), (3,2)? Or, that plus (1,2,3), (3,2,1), (2,3,1), (1,3,2), (3,1,2), (2,1,3) ?

Answer (score 0):

We should start by drawing a distinction between the time complexity of your code vs what you might actually be looking for.

In your case, you have a set of nested loops (a for and a while). So, worst case, which is what Big O is based on, you would do each of those while loops *n* times. But you also have that outer loop which would also be done *n* times.

O(n) * O(n) = O(n) <sup>2</sup>

Which is not very good. Now, while not really so bad with this example, imagine if you were looking for "what a piece of work is man" in all of the Library of Congress or even in the collected works of Shakespeare.

[image: Big O - time graphs]

On the plus side, you can refactor your code and get it down quite a bit.